# Trying to find out what app is being used with the “sharing” notification as pictured

Tags: applications, notifications

Sharing notification-top left of phone
Which is that app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the notification tray and the application's name should be written there for each notification. (Android 7.0 Nougat and above)

---

Here are two examples:
[image: illustration of point]
As you can see, the app name "Termux" is visible next to the application's notification icon.

---

Here's another example, where you can see the app name "Hangouts" is written next the application's notification icon.

[image: Another image]

None of this has anything to do with rooting your device, it's built in to stock Android.

Comment: a) Termux doesn't require root / b) I'm trying to point out that the notification-causing application's name is written at the top. I'll give another example then.

Comment: Sorry my mistake got what you meant